Using multiple aggregations in a pivot in oracle
I have a case where I am trying to split a data set into before and after, and compute an error rate for each. The final tabular result I want us:



definition
before
after




foo
.27
.11


baz
.41
.32



And, I need a little help here. Maybe there is even a function that just does this.
For starters, it doesn't like my combined sum()/count(), it tells me that's invalid sql. So, removing count and just using sum I then get the layout I want, kinda (the columns are named funny), but the values are all null. So, I am not sure what I'm missing and would appreciate some input
Sql similar to what I want:
select * from (
    select when, DEFINITION, state from (
        select 'before 'as when,
           definition,
           state
        from (
         select DEFINITION, state from REQUEST_HISTORY where processend < :SOME_DATE
        )
        union all
        select 'after ' as when,
           definition,
           state
        from (
            select DEFINITION, state from REQUEST_HISTORY where processend >= :SOME_DATE
        )
    )
)pivot ((sum(case when STATE IN (10, 15, 19) then 1 else 0 end) / count(*)) for when in ('before', 'after'))

sql that executes but produces the wrong results:
select * from (
    select when, DEFINITION, state from (
        select 'before 'as when,
           definition,
           state
        from (
         select DEFINITION, state from REQUEST_HISTORY where processend < :SOME_DATE
        )
        union all
        select 'after ' as when,
           definition,
           state
        from (
            select DEFINITION, state from REQUEST_HISTORY where processend >= :SOME_DATE
        )
    )
)pivot (sum(case when STATE IN (10, 15, 19) then 1 else 0 end)  for when in ('before', 'after'))

produces:



DEFINITION
'before'_ERROR_RATE
'after'_ERROR_RATE




JobDefinition://apps/ess/hcm/common/dataLoader/HRC_DL_TRANSFER_OBJECT
null
null


JobDefinition://apps/ess/hcm/applicationsSecurity/AseImportUsersAndRolesJob
null
null


JobDefinition://apps/ess/financials/generalLedger/programs/common/CrossValidationRuleViolationReport
null
null


JobSet://apps/ess/custom/NOVHCMDailyProcesses
null
null


JobDefinition://apps/ess/custom/Shared Folders/Custom/Integrations/LogFire/EXTRACTWMSRMADEVREPORT
null
null


JobDefinition://apps/ess/scm/costing/costAccounting/runControl/RefreshMaterializedViews
null
null


JobSet://apps/ess/custom/CSTIMPORTREVENUELINES5/CST_EMEA_IMPORT_REVENUE_LINE_5
null
null


JobDefinition://apps/ess/custom/AUDIT/POSTING_QUEUE
null
null


JobDefinition://apps/ess/custom/HIERARCHY/HIERARCHY_37
null
null


JobDefinition://apps/ess/custom/REFERENCE/REFERENCE_8
null
null




You haven't provided any sample data so its difficult to determine what logic you are expecting to implement. However, you appear to want to use conditional aggregation and although you could use SUM()/COUNT() you can also use AVG:
SELECT definition,
       AVG(
         CASE WHEN processend < :SOME_DATE
         THEN CASE WHEN STATE IN (10, 15, 19) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         END
       ) AS before,
       AVG(
         CASE WHEN processend >= :SOME_DATE
         THEN CASE WHEN STATE IN (10, 15, 19) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         END
       ) AS after
FROM   REQUEST_HISTORY
GROUP BY
       definition

or
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT definition,
         CASE WHEN processend < :SOME_DATE THEN 'before' ELSE 'after' END
           AS when,
         CASE WHEN STATE IN (10, 15, 19) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS state
  FROM   REQUEST_HISTORY
)
PIVOT (AVG(state) FOR when IN ('before' AS before, 'after' AS after))

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE REQUEST_HISTORY (definition, processend, state) AS
  SELECT 'foo', DATE '1970-01-01', 10 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 27 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'foo', DATE '1970-01-01', 11 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 73 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'foo', DATE '1980-01-01', 10 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 11 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'foo', DATE '1980-01-01', 11 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 89 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'bar', DATE '1970-01-01', 10 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 41 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'bar', DATE '1970-01-01', 11 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 59 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'bar', DATE '1980-01-01', 10 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 32 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'bar', DATE '1980-01-01', 11 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 68;

Both output, when :SOME_DATE is 1975-01-01:



DEFINITION
BEFORE
AFTER




foo
.27
.11


bar
.41
.32



or maybe, depending on whether you want to count across the entire definition group or just within the before/after partition within each group:
SELECT definition,
       AVG(
         CASE
         WHEN processend < :SOME_DATE
         AND  state IN (10, 15, 19)
         THEN 1 ELSE 0
         END
       ) AS before,
       AVG(
         CASE
         WHEN processend >= :SOME_DATE
         AND  state IN (10, 15, 19)
         THEN 1 ELSE 0
         END
       ) AS after
FROM   REQUEST_HISTORY
GROUP BY
       definition

Which, for the sample data, outputs:



DEFINITION
BEFORE
AFTER




foo
.135
.055


bar
.205
.16



(But with different sample data may output your expected results.)
fiddle
